# Meaning of a phrase from a sitcom

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases

A group of friends went to the theater. The play was awful. Then, one of them says:

> Did anybody else feel like they just wanted to peel the skin off their
>   body, to have something else to do?

I know the *translation* of this phase but I could not understand its *meaning*. By the way, it was extracted from the scripts of *Friends*, episode 6, first season. The episode starts with a part of the play. After that, we have the first talk of some of the friends: "God. I feel violated.". So, comes the phase I marked above.

If possible, I would like some help to understand this sentence. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Did anybody else feel like they just wanted to [peel the skin off their body][stick their fingers in a fan][eat a bag of gravel], to have something else to do?" The experience of the play was so excruciatingly unpleasant that it may be more pleasant to undergo the alternatives. (_Why_ is that funny? That's LitCrit and strictly OT here.)

Comment: Dear P. E. Dant, then does the pronoun *they* refer to the friends? I was thinking it would refer to the actors of the play...

Comment: In this sentence, _they_ refers to _anybody else._

Comment: Hum, now I see why I was confused. Thank you so much!

Comment: Would you like to answer or could I do?

Comment: Please do answer your own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As P. E. Dant kindly commented, the experience of the play was so unpleasant that one of the friends considered it as a pain greater than to peel the skin off her body. He also pointed that in the emphasized sentence, *they* refers to *anybody else* and not to the actors in the play, as I was thinking.

Comment: It's not just anybody, Monica's quote is directed to Rachel, Chandler, and Ross ("*their body*", read: "*your body*") since she is talking to them as a group. [Skin flaying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flaying) is a well known and ancient slow form of execution.

Comment: @Peter rgm's analysis is correct. His answer does not claim that the referent is "just anybody". The pronoun _they_ in the sentence refers to the phrase _anybody else,_ as he says. What _anybody else_ refers to is interesting, but it was not addressed in the question.